# Streaming a stream from website to Twitch with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, ip-camera, twitch

Is it possible to stream a website with a livestream (i.e. ip-camera) via FFMPEG to Twitch? If yes, does anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  FFmpeg has a built-in RTMP client (which is the protocol you'll use to send your video data to Twitch), FLV (the wrapper for your audio and video data), H.264 (the video codec), and AAC (the audio codec).

First, find your RTMP ingest URL:  https://help.twitch.tv/s/twitch-ingest-recommendation

Now, just run FFmpeg as you normally would to ingest your input, but set some additional parameters for the output:

```
ffmpeg [your input parameters] -vcodec libx264 -b:v 5M -acodec aac -b:a 256k -f flv [your RTMP URL]
```

Comment: May want to set KF interval e.g. `-g 60`.

Comment: @Gyan Valid point, yes!  Is that standard for Twitch now, or just low latency streams?  Any other recommended flags they want?

Comment: Also @J.Doe see if you can use NVENC when setting up your codec.  You'll have much better performance.

Comment: Here's the recommended settings list: https://stream.twitch.tv/encoding/

Comment: @Brad Also [`-maxrate` and `-bufsize`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites).

Comment: New ingest links are https://help.twitch.tv/s/twitch-ingest-recommendation